# Logging events as an Office 2007 application opens

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007, event-log

Is it possible to log what a Microsoft Office 2007 application does as it starts up.

We are having an issue with Word where it hangs on the splash screen for a particular user and no one else and would like to find out what is causing it to hang.

Windows event viewer only shows that the application was terminated unexpectedly because of a hang.

Comment: The user is on Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) suite to try and find out what the problem is.

In particular, Process Explorer and Process Monitor may help you in find out what is causing the hang.